# how to allow accented charaters in oracle using regexp_replace in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Case:
To accept person_name satisfying following criteria:

1. Allows any alphabetic symbols
2. Space
3. Dash
4. Apostrophe
5. Accent grave

Some pre-calculation has been performed to store the name in the string "PERSON_NAME"

LOGIC: `` SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PERSON_NAME,'[^A-Za-z .`''-]+',''),0,50) ``

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('cafè','[^A-Z|a-z| |.|`|''|-]+'),0,50) 
    FROM dual;
```

Passing almost all cases except in case of accented characters:

For example:

Expected result: cafè [i.e symbol above e ` should not be filtered out]

Actual Result: caf

Comment: what should be filtered out ? I mean what's the difference with the original string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
select SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('cafè-` t *'' {','[[:digit:]]') ,0,50) as "String"
  from dual;

String
--------------
cafè-` t *' {
```

since there's no information about numeric expressions in your restriction list.

Comment: Hi, your column aliasing `as "String"` results in an error being thrown: `SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: Thank you, @BarbarosÖzhan.

One last doubt:

Is it a bad practice to put the accented vowels as a part of the REGEX itself?


select substr(REGEXP_REPLACE('cafè','[^A-Z|a-z| |.|`|''|-|À|È|Ì|Ò|Ù|à|è|ì|ò|ù]+'),0,50) from dual;

I want to allow to allow only the accent grave[`] vowels.
eg: allowed -vis-à-vis [result = visàvis]
      not allowed: Cissé [result = Ciss]

Comment: @Saiprasadshankar you're welcome. I think there's no need to list explicitly all the accented chars, if you use `[[:digit:]]`, but I didn't understand from your last sample that you want to remove or not to remove non-alphabetic chars ...

Comment: Hello @BarbarosÖzhan,

Another extension of this task is to allow a minimum of 2 charachters and a maximum of 50.

In my substr() I have taken 0 and 50.
So I I start from the beginning of the string and get only a maximum of 50 charachtcers.

Is there a way to specify the minimum range as well?

As using SUBSTR(2,50) skips the first few charachters as that specifies the starting point.

Comment: @Saiprasadshankar can you explain what you mean with an example?